# In PowerPoint, how can you match an object's 3d perspective to that of a static image?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, 3d-graphics, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

My question is easiest to illustrate with an example.

I work with early-stage startups, so often make PowerPoint "mock-ups" of what software will look like when displayed on a computer screen. I start with a transparency of a computer screen or tablet, and use PowerPoint's 3d perspective tools to get my mock-up to match the angle.

A picture might make this clearer.

[image]

Getting the perspective to match is a lot of trial-and-error, and the result never looks quite right. Is there a "proper" way to do this? Is there a way to calculate the proper rotation values, rather than approach by trial-and-error?

Comment: "Is there any way to do this that isn't" isn't what?

Comment: Use a proper drawing tool that handles 3d rotation correctly. PowerPoint is a presentation tool not a drawing tool. It's like using a hammer to drive screws. Use the right tool for the job. Having said that asking for software recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: It had never occurred to me to do the free transform outside of PPT and then reimport into the slide. That worked rather well. Missed the forest for the trees...

Comment: Searching for"drawing tools for software prototyping" might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Providing an answer to my own question, so that that my solution is documented for future readers.

Following a suggestion in the comments, I pulled up Pixlr and used the free transform tool there to match the frame perspective. I then exported everything back into my PPT, as a PNG with transparent background.

It had never occurred to me to do part of this outside PPT and then re-import. But it was really much faster (seconds!) and the result was far better than using PPT 3d effects for this...